# How to define a new debugflag in gem5?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debugging, memory-address, gem5

gem5 version:v21.2.0.0，add a new debugflag in src/mem/cache/SConscript,

recompile with scons/build/ARM/gem.opt，

and in build/ARM/debug file still don't have new debugflag.hh

in this version, how to define a new debugflag to show the details about addr, pc addr, cacheline's index, cacheline's offset, write/read, access lenth, L1 hit/miss and index, L2 hit/miss and index

Answer (score 0):

[Per the gem5 documentation](https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/debugging_and_testing/debugging/trace_based_debugging), to add a DebugFlag you have to "add new debug flags simply by adding DebugFlag() command to any SConscript file (preferably the one nearest where you are using the new flag). If you use a debug flag in a C++ source file, you would need to include the header file debug/.hh in that file."

For example, if you wanted to add the flag to `src/mem/cache/SConscript`, you could add `DebugFlag("SampleFlag")` to the SConscript. To compile, you *cannot* use the `gem5.fast` compilation target (the documentation states that DebugFlags are not included to optimize compilation), but the `debug/SampleFlag.hh` should be created automatically in the `build/<ISA>/` directory (where the path would be `build/ISA/debug/SampleFlag.hh`).

Then, to add `SampleFlag` to the `src/mem/cache/cache.cc` file, you need to include `debug/SampleFlag.hh` at the beginning of the file, and can then use the syntax `DPRINTF(SampleFlag, "<formatting string of addr, pc addr, cacheline's index, cacheline's offset, write/read, access lenth, L1 hit/miss and index, L2 hit/miss and index>")`.

Answer (score -1):

Se.py is not the right file to add your debugging flags. Go to options.py, and add as many as you want in there so that you can pass them in the command line when you run simulations. You could check for these flags in cache.cc to do your data (hits, misses, address and pc on l1d cache).

Comment: The question does not mention `se.py`. Furthermore, you can add command line flags in the `configs/common/Options.py` file, but debug flags refer to something else in gem5. Per [the gem5 documentation](https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/debugging_and_testing/debugging/trace_based_debugging).

Comment: That is what I mentioned my man: options.py. Maybe I misread the question ‍♂️